# How can I order objects according to some attribute of the child in OData?

Tags: odata

I'm trying to do some custom sorting in OData using this URL

```
localhost:82/odata.svc/ComponentPresentations?$filter=TemplateId eq 2894 and publicationId eq 10&$expand=Component/Keywords?$orderby=Title desc
```

Where `Component`is a property of `ComponentPresentation` and `Keywords` is property of `Component`, and I want to sort the ComponentPresentation according to the keyword's `Title` attribute. But keywords nor title is a property of Component Presentation

Is there a way to sort the results according to the attribute of Keword's title? Which is a Child of Component, which is a child of ComponentPresentation?

Comment: @VladL above... (sorry, I don't have the rep points to comment), I don't think that works either. I just tried it and added Quantity to the select statement for the Order_Details: http://services.odata.org/V4/Northwind/Northwind.svc/Orders?$select=OrderID&$expand=Order_Details($select=UnitPrice,Quantity;$orderby=Quantity) It does not appear that the Order_Details are being sorted by Quantity.

Answer (score 16):

Just want to mention that it is possible since OData V4. You can nest as many expands/selects/orderby/filters as you wish. Now it is as simple as

http://services.odata.org/V4/Northwind/Northwind.svc/Orders?$select=OrderID&$expand=Order_Details($select=UnitPrice;$orderby=Quantity)

Comment: the syntax is correct, but the nested orderby doesn't seem to change anything in the result.

Comment: @sroll I've spent a lot of time with sample OData services from odata.org and noticed that you get different results at different times, if the service is not down at all ;) Try it with TripPin http://www.odata.org/odata-services/

Comment: If the syntax is correct, it's weird that it doesn't work then :s

Comment: As far I understand, it would not be possible with the version 2??

Comment: @inane not even in V3

Comment: But with the v2 is impossible?

Comment: @inane v1, v2 and v3 - impossible

Comment: This syntax is correct but the problem is it doesn't sort the Orders it only sorts the order_details within each of the orders.

Comment: @RonnBlack sure, because it is applied to order_details :)

Comment: @VladL  In my `$expand=az_Job($select=az_JobId,az_Code,az_Name;$orderby=az_Name desc)`, I have specify `desc` in `$orderby`, unfortunately it didn't work.  What did I miss?

Comment: Can I ask you where did you find that syntax rule? I mean the comma to separate more statement inside an `$expand`. Thank you.

Answer (score 14):

It is possible to sort the results by a nested single-cardinality property, for example: http://services.odata.org/V3/Northwind/Northwind.svc/Orders?$top=50&$expand=Customer&$orderby=Customer/City

AFAIK, it's not possible to do this with a navigation property that has a cardinality of many (though it would be useful in expand scenarios to order what comes back in the expanded feed).

Answer (score 2):

append order by with  expand object/field on the end of the query

localhost:82/odata.svc/ComponentPresentations?$filter=TemplateId eq 2894 and publicationId eq 10&$expand=Component/Keywords?$orderby=Component/Title desc