# OData V4 $expand nested $filter and $orderby -- combine $filter and $orderby inside expand

Tags: asp.net-web-api2, odata, odata-v4

I currently have an OData V4 service that has the following model.
"Category" -- "Codes"
For each category there can be many codes.

I need to $expand the Codes, $filter where Active = true and then $orderby Codes.Description.

Currently the following works fine without ordering.

> odata/Categories?$expand=Codes($filter=Active eq true)

This does not work.

> odata/Categories?$expand=Codes($filter=Active eq true&$orderby=Description)

I receive "The query specified in the URI is not valid. Syntax error at position 12." & "Syntax error at position 12 in 'Description)'."

Basically it is reading the last ")" after "Description" as an error.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I was not able to find this in the OData V4 documents but I did find a similar example here "[How can I order objects according to some attribute of the child in OData?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12571618/how-can-i-order-objects-according-to-some-attribute-of-the-child-in-odata)"

> http://services.odata.org/V4/Northwind/Northwind.svc/Orders?$select=OrderID&$expand=Order_Details($select=UnitPrice;$orderby=Quantity)

The key I was missing is

> ;

This goes between the filter and orderby.
Here is the working url

> odata/Categories?$expand=Codes($filter=Active eq true;$orderby=Description)

Answer (score 0):

OData V4  grouping last  records get your service

```
odata/Categories?$expand=Codes($top=1;$orderby=Description)
```